# sharepoint 2010 - How to display a video on a dialog window?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am new to sharepoint. My requirement is to display a video on a dialog window.I tried using the media webpart but that does not have the option to open the video on a dialog box. What are my best options to implement this functionality? Please advise.

I am using sandbox Sharepoint 2010 for my intranet site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the content editor web part to achieve this.

First, are you able to open the dialog box? is that dialog box is you custom application page?

If yes, then Edit page and add one content editor web part to that page.

Select that content editor web part and you will see the  Format Text Tab -> HTML

Clcik Edit HTML

Put you html code of IFrame to show the video in this.

If everything goes fine,.

You can see your video

Let me know the outcome.

Thanks

Comment: I am trying to implement the code from this site http://zieglers.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/how-to-play-flash-video-in-sharepoint/ but after I add the script to the HTML source on content editor web part the video is no showing up.